# Coding a multiple integral function in R

Tags: r, bayesian, integral

With the goal of turning the following into a function, I was wondering how I can write the following double integral in terms of R codes?: ($\bar{x} = \mu$):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `pi0` and `pi1` implement your functions $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ in a vectorized way, a possible solution is:

```
integral <- function(n, mu, s, pi0, pi1) {

  C <- (2 * pi)^(-n/2) 
  C * integrate(f = function(sigmavec) sapply(sigmavec, function(sigma) {
    integrate(f = function(delta) {

      exp(-n/2 * ((mu / sigma - delta)^2 + (s / sigma)^2)) * pi1(delta)

    }, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)$value

  }) * pi0(sigmavec) / (sigmavec^n), lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value

}

# Tests
integral(n = 1, mu = 0, s = 1, pi0 = dnorm, pi1 = dnorm)
# [1] 0.0473819
integral(n = 1, mu = 0, s = 1, pi0 = function(sigma) 1/sigma, pi1 = dcauchy)
# [1] 0.2615783
```

Comment: Use `pi1 = function(x) dcauchy(x, scale = 0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if this question is on topic, but I am open to answer.

May be you should ask a more general question, how to write/computing integral 
using computer program (code)? There at least are two ways

1. Using numerical integration, such as Monte Carlo method
2. Using symbolic toolbox to solve the problem analytically and plugin the numerical value.

Examples on $\int_0^1 x^2$

```
f<-function(x){
  x^2
}
curve(f,0,1)

# method 1
integrate(f,lower=0,upper = 1)

# method 2
library(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x")
f <- function(x) {
  x^2
}
f2=yacas(yacas(Integrate(f(x), x)))
f2

x <- 1
Eval(f2)
```

Comment: But remember my case is a double integration, so I need help with that, honestly not simple integrations?