# how to integrate of a function with multiple parameters w.r.t one of them in R?

Tags: r, optimization, integrate

I have a 2 variable function in R which I want to integrate w.r.t one of them and then optimize it w.r.t the other one. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4752675) of what you are trying to do. In this case,  can you provide us with an example function that you would like to integrate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coding a multiple integral function in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095957/coding-a-multiple-integral-function-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not provide an example of the sort of function that you would like to integrate and then optimize,  so I will use a somewhat arbitrary choice as an example.

> f(y) = ∫<sub><sub>0</sub></sub><sup><sup>y</sup></sup> (y-1) x<sup>2</sup> dx

You can write this function in R using the `integrate` function and then use `optimize` to find a minimum over some specified range.

```
DefInt = function(y) { integrate(function(x) { (y-1)*x*x },0,y)$value }
optimize(DefInt, c(-2,2))
$minimum
[1] 0.7499972
$objective
[1] -0.03515625
```